# Auto-truncating fields at max_length in Django CharFields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a field that has a `max_length` set. When I save a model instance, and the field's value is greater than `max_length`, Django enforces that `max_length` at the database level. (See Django docs on models: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField.max_length)

However, since I am using Postgres, I receive a `DatabaseError` exception like this:

```
DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(1000)
```

I would prefer to instead auto-truncate the value (so I don't have an exception). Now, I can do this manually, but what I would really want is to have all of my models auto-truncate the value. (Not necessarily intelligently. Just cutting it off at the 999th character is fine.)

Should I just write a custom class that imports from models.Model and override the save() method, looping through each _meta.field, checking for the max_length, and then truncating? That seems inelegant and there must be a better way.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could create a custom field that auto-truncates the field (I think this code should work, but double-check it):

```
class TruncatingCharField(models.CharField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(TruncatingCharField,self).get_prep_value(value)
        if value:
            return value[:self.max_length]
        return value
```

Then, instead of using `models.CharField` in your `models.py` file, you'd just use TruncatingCharField instead.

[`get_prep_value`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/#django.db.models.get_prep_value) prepares the value for a field for insertion in the database, so it's the ideal place to truncate.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: where to place it?

Comment: been using this one glady for over 2 years with only one thing to highlight: after using `.create` (or variants that result in a create such as `get_or_create`), in-memory instance won't have the field truncated. good to keep in mind!
`refresh_from_db` shows it properly truncated but not so nice to have to refresh object right after creating it..

Comment: I couldn't find anyway to control this from the Field class itself, so I ended up adding `Field.get_prep_value()` to the `save()` methods of models with a TruncatingCharField...

Comment: Before slicing the value, we should strip() it.

Comment: This was helpful. I will just add the usage bit of the truncate class for anyone for whom it may not be obvious.
description = TruncatingCharField(max_length=1024)

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you use a TextField? From the manual:

> For large amounts of text, use
>   TextField.

Comment: Yeah, looking at what you've written, if you want it cut off at the 999th character that suggests to me that a TextField might be a better choice.

Comment: Good answer, but probably for another question.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `ModelForm`. ModelForm enforces a validation, setting its default max_length to model field's max_length property, and raising proper validation error when `form.is_valid()` is called. That way you don't have to save the form, until form is validated.

Or, if you want to silently pass the validation and truncate suits best to you, write a simple django form, and write a clean method that truncates input string to the max_length and return stripped data. Take data from `form.cleaned_data` after form is validated and save the object.

All considering the fact, Forms are designed to validate data before going to DB.

Answer (score -4):

*That seems inelegant and there must be a better way.*

The only reason the truncate behavior ever happens in the first place is because of MySQL's failure to adhere to the SQL Standard.  The throwing of an exception is the correct response when attempting to INSERT a string into a VARCHAR field that is not wide enough to hold it.  MySQL truncates and inserts instead.

If you want to silently corrupt your data, then you'll have to do it manually somehow--PostgreSQL will never do it for you.

Comment: The question is about Django, not about PostgreSQL. I like PostgreSQL adhering to the standard and raising an error, but I'd (also, like the OP) like a way to let Django know that it's OK to truncate (before trying to insert).

Comment: OK, doing this by default is a misfeature. But having an option to do this automatically is a feature.