# value too long for type character varying(N)

Tags: django, postgresql

My model has a SlugField. When I try to save an instance of this model with the slug field set to a string which is longer than the field's `max_length` parameter (which is 50 by default), I get the following error from Postgresql: `value too long for type character varying(50)`.

Is not Django (or Postgresql) supposed to truncate the string when saving? What can I do to fix it other than truncating it manually every time?

Comment: Make the column wider. PostgreSQL (unlike MySQL) will not silently mangle your data to fit the column.

Comment: If you happen not to care about losing some data for whatever reason, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459843/auto-truncating-fields-at-max-length-in-django-charfields) may prove useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either install [south](http://south.aeracode.org/) and resize the column (best option), or create a [pre_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save) and add code to truncate the field to 50 characters before it is saved. Something like:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from app.model import mymodel

def truncater(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if sender is mymodel:
        if len(instance.fieldname)>50:
            instance.fieldname = instance.fieldname[:50]
pre_save.connect(truncater, sender=mymodel)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to resize the column with South?

Comment: @AndreBoos: That would be another topic, but South would allow you to migrate your database schema. You change your model, run schemamigration and migrate, and your DB schema will be updated to match your models.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add something in your view that tests to see if the slug will be >50 characters, and if so truncates it.

```
if len(content) >50:
    content = content[:50]
else:
    pass
slug = content
```