# Django form/database error: value too long for type character varying(4)

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql

I'm trying to save a stripe (the billing service) company id [around 200 characters or so] to my database in Django.

The specific error is:

```
database error: value too long for type character varying(4)
```

**How can I enable Django to allow for longer values?**

I saw:
[value too long for type character varying(N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747922/value-too-long-for-type-character-varyingn)
and:
[Django fixture fails, stating "DatabaseError: value too long for type character varying(50)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803552/django-fixture-fails-stating-databaseerror-value-too-long-for-type-character)

- my database is already encoded for UTF-8, according to my webhost.
- **EDIT** : I see that one answer recommends making the column wider. **Does that involve modifying the PostgreSQL database?**

My specific system is Webfaction, CentOs shared machine, Django running on PostgreSQL. I would really appreciate a conceptual overview of what's going on and how I can fix it.

Comment: Yes, make the column wider. Type in python manage.py dbshell to get into your database shell. You can manually modify the table with `ALTER TABLE` statements, drop the database and run `syncdb` again, or  learn and use a database migration tool like `South`

Comment: @YujiTomita I think thats a full enough response to be an answer imho.

Comment: Can you post the model you're trying to save to, or are you using someone else's code? You usually set the varchar length as a max_length parameter to the CharField in question.

Comment: @JamesKhoury Now I had to post an answer, and it took more work!

Comment: @YujiTomita Thanks for your help. I am going to try this today.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, make the column wider. The error message is quite clear: your 200 characters are too big to fit in a varchar(4).

First, update your model fields `max_length` attribute from 4 to a number that you expect will be long enough to contain the data you're feeding it.

Next up you have to update the database column itself as [django will not automatically update existing columns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#syncdb).

Here are a few options:

1:
Drop the database and run syncdb again. **Warning: you will lose *all* your data.**

2: Manually update the column via SQL:

Type in `python manage.py dbshell` to get into your database shell and type in

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN my_column TYPE VARCHAR(200)
```

3: Learn and use a database migration tool like [django south](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/) which will help keep your database updated with your model code.

Comment: You could drop the 200 if it isn't a requirement: ["There is no performance difference among these three types, apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html)

Comment: I would +1 this just for the comment `"you have to update the database column itself "` thats something i often trip up on.

Comment: @James Khoury - this answer was your fault! And I thought I could get away with a comment and be on my way. : )

Answer (score 2):

JUST IN CASE SOMEONE RUNS INTO THIS ERROR FOR DJANGO 3 and POSTGRES.

STEP 1: Go to your migration folder.

STEP 2: Navigate to your recent migration file.

STEP 3: Check for the operations list in the migration file.

STEP 4: Update the field or the table column max_length to the higher number to accommodate your data.

Answer (score 1):

Using Django 1.11 and Postgres 9.6 I ran into this, for no apparent reason.

I set *max_length=255* in the migration file and executed:

manage.py migrate

Then I set the correct length on the Model's *max_length* and ran another *makemigrations* and the ran *migrate* again.