# Django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying (3)

Tags: python, django, models

Not sure why I'm getting this error as none of my fields are set to limit 3 except one, which I know will never exceed 3. I'm able to run `python manage.py makemigrations` without any issue, but once I `migrate` the error pops up. My model looks like this:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  player_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  player_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  team_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  team_abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=3)
  age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  gp = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  w = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  l = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  w_pct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  min = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fgm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fga = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fg_pct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fg3m = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fg3a = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fg3_pct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  ftm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  fta = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  ft_pct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  oreb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  dreb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  reb = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  ast = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  tov = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  stl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  blk = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  blka = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  pf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  pfd = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  pts = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  plus_minus = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  nba_fantasy_pts = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  dd2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  td3 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=3)
  gp_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  w_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  l_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  w_pct_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  min_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fgm_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fga_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fg_pct_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fg3m_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fg3a_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fg3_pct_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  ftm_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  fta_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  ft_pct_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  oreb_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  dreb_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  reb_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  ast_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  tov_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  stl_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  blk_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  blka_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  pf_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  pfd_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  pts_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  plus_minus_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  nba_fantasy_pts_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  dd2_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  td3_rank = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  cfid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
  cfparams = models.CharField(max_length=18)
```

I'm pretty new to Python, so maybe it's something simple that I just haven't seen before but I haven't found an answer that has been able to help yet. Here is the
[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pudCz.png).

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: just added it. thanks for looking.

Comment: Dont add it as an image. Add it as text in the question.

Comment: did you change any max_length field in your models.py ?

Comment: "which I know will never exceed 3" - I couldn't possibly count the number of times I knew some data couldn't be too large, until it turned out it was. Are you sure you're putting the correct values in each field? Can you add logging before you insert to see *exactly* what values you have? Maybe fields are transposed, or there's trailing whitespace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django form/database error: value too long for type character varying(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484689/django-form-database-error-value-too-long-for-type-character-varying4)

Comment: @ytsejam I increased the max_length to hopefully catch that error, but I got the same thing.

Comment: @ryachza I am using the correct values. I have json file with the data inside and I made sure that it was correct. That's what I thought at first too!

Comment: Do you already have a version of the Player Class in your database backend, and if so does it have any existing data in it? Could be that there is data in the database in the team_abbreviation column which may be already longer than 3 characters.  Hence why you are getting the error on migration as opposed to makemigration.  Just a wild guess.

Comment: As @SachinKukreja told in comment check the answer , drop the db and run makemigrations and migrate again , you will loose your data.

Comment: @cander i did have a version from previous migrations, but I went in and deleted the class from the django_migrations table.

Comment: I'll try dropping the table and starting the migration fresh.