# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) value too long for type character varying(20)

Tags: python, heroku, sqlalchemy

Trying to register a user on heroku, but i get this error in the heroku log, and i get an internal error, and i referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747922/value-too-long-for-type-character-varyingn)

The rest of the site works, i just cant register when im on heroku, works on local host.

this is for flask, any recommendations ?

```
>>> from app import db,models
>>> u = models.User(username='susan', password='janemba133')
>>> db.session.add(u)
>>> db.session.commit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 157, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 801, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 392, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 372, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2019, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2137, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2101, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 373, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 532, in execute
    uow
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 174, in save_obj
    mapper, table, insert)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 800, in _emit_insert_statements
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1010, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 200, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) value too long for type character varying(20)
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO "user" (username, password) VALUES (%(username)s, %(password)s) RETURNING "user".id'] [parameters: {'username': 'susan', 'password': '$2b$09$Vez1laSR6yrYxARBQGzF.Oxl/rJVtxN2.uuaXzJK6zberdikWy98K'}]
```

**Models.py**

```
from app import app, db, bcrypt, slugify, JWT, jwt_required, current_identity, safe_str_cmp
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, DateTime, func
from app import (TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer
                          as Serializer, BadSignature, SignatureExpired)

import datetime


class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    # posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password, 9)


    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True


    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return  (self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username



class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer,  primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(80), index=True, nullable=True)
    author = db.relationship("User",backref=db.backref("posts",lazy="dynamic"))

    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    def __init__(self, title, body, slug,author):
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.slug = slugify(title).lower()
        self.author = author
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
gunicorn==19.4.5
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
psycopg2==2.7.1
SQLAlchemy==1.0.12
Werkzeug==0.11.9
simplejson==3.10.0
six==1.10.0
slugify==0.0.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.2.2
Flask-Jsonpify==1.5.0
Flask-JWT==0.3.2
Flask-Login==0.4.0
Flask-Migrate==2.0.3
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-WhooshAlchemy==0.56
Flask-Session==0.3.1
PyJWT==1.4.2
bcrypt==3.1.3
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it, what i had to do is increase my password max to 120 instead of 20, because it is using bcrypt, so it can take up alot of characters.

destroy the database,
and do a

```
db.create_all()
```

and you should be good to go.