# Custom field in Django get_prep_value() has no effect

Tags: django, django-models

So, I've made a similar class to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3460942/781909). It looks like:

```
class TruncatingCharField(models.CharField):
    description = _("String (truncated to %(max_length)s)")

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super(TruncatingCharField, self).get_prep_value(value)
        if value:
            value = value[:self.max_length]
        return value
```

I would expect that instantiating a model with this field with strings longer than the threshold should trigger truncation. However this appears not to be the case:

```
class NewTruncatedField(models.Model):
    trunc = TruncatingCharField(max_length=10)


class TestTruncation(TestCase):

    def test_accepted_length(self):
        trunc = 'a'*5
        obj = NewTruncatedField(trunc=trunc)
        self.assertEqual(len(obj.trunc), 5)

    def test_truncated_length(self):
        trunc = 'a'*15
        obj = NewTruncatedField(trunc=trunc)
        self.assertEqual(len(obj.trunc), 10)
```

The first test passes, as would be expected, but the second fails, as the field does not truncate its value. The `get_prep_value()` method is definitely being called (tested via breakpoints), and the output of `value` at the point of return is correctly truncated.

Why then is the value of the field in the `obj` object not truncated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe `get_prep_value()` only effects what is saved to the DB, not the internal value of the Python object.

Try overriding [`to_python()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.to_python) and moving your logic there.