# Django model - set default charfield in lowercase

Tags: django, django-models

How to set default charfield in lowercase?
This is my model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.username.lower()
```

I tried the `__init__` but it doesn't work. I want to make the username in lowercase every time new record saved. Thanks.

Comment: you may try a this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350681/django-lowercasecharfield

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just do it in the save method. ie, override the `save` method of `Model` class.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.username = self.username.lower()
    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's important to point out this only helps when your model updates go through save. If you write code that does an .update() on a queryset, you don't go through save, so can still end up with uppercase letters in your database field.

Comment: @aggieNick02 for this case, a pre_save signal will help.

Comment: No, it does not. The recent edit to this answer should be reverted as it is not correct. From the django docs: "Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run any save() methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save signals" (source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

Comment: Don't override `save`, it'll break other Django methods such as `get_or_create`.

Comment: I found this solution worked fine when you were making new records. But it doesn't work when you are updating existing records. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Apologies, I had made a dumb error with my specific code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143480/i-have-over-written-the-save-method-but-the-new-code-is-only-being-applied-to/64143624#64143624

Comment: It would be better to use `to_python` on the field

Comment: This not the best way todo this at all.. and the below from #Danil is certainly the preferred nd arguably the more sustainable and reusable

Answer (score 76):

While overwriting `save()` method is a valid solution. I found it useful to deal with this on a `Field` level as opposed to the `Model` level by overwriting `get_prep_value()` method.

This way if you ever want to reuse this field in a different model, you can adopt the same consistent strategy. Also the logic is separated from the save method, which you may also want to overwrite for different purposes.

For this case you would do this:

```
class NameField(models.CharField):
    # Ensure valid values will always be using just lowercase
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = super().get_prep_value(value)
        return value if value is None else value.lower()

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    name = NameField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Small typo. SnpField should be NameField. Thank you for this method. I appreciate the reuse-ability.

Comment: This solution is excellent.

I added unique=True to SlugField and lowered it in save(), but I got IntegrityError if the same value passed but not lowercase.

your solution helped me overcome it. Thanks

Comment: +1, this `get_prep_value` method also used when accessing to the DB, e.g. I created an UUID field, that deletes all '-' symbols and do uppercase, then I created an object and trying to get it from the DB:
`Unit.objects.get(uuid="dc048edf-a08c41c9-b8a2-10e9-7b8752a8") -> 
<Unit: Unit object (DC048EDFA08C41C9B8A210E97B8752A8)>
`

Comment: Out of curiosity.  Is `get_prep_value` the best function to override when creating `NameField`?  In another answer by wiesion, he used `to_python` instead of `get_prep_value`.  Any thoughts on that?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50895814/8702081

Comment: @Valachio according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093407/custom-field-in-django-get-prep-value-has-no-effect), "the get_prep_value() only effects what is saved to the DB, not the internal value of the Python object"

Comment: Should it be something more like:
```
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        value = value.lower()
        return super().get_prep_value(value)
```
Also, casting it to a string will cover up any non-string values which are attempted for insertion, which seems bad to me.

Comment: I would first call `super` method of [`CharField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/78470043ae4b8def7914badcd05bb1877c8a0aa4/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1197) like: `value = super().get_prep_value(value)`. And than `if value: value.strip().lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a **recipient_name** field that I needed to make all lower case when it is stored on DB

```
class LowerField(models.CharField):

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value).lower()

class Recipients(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='recipients', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    recipient_account_number = models.IntegerField()
    recipient_name = LowerField(max_length=30)
    recipient_bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Transaction Date')
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipient_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('recipient-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Similarly, you can apply to another table called **Transactions** in your app, like this

```
class Transactions(models.Model):

    transaction_type = (
        ('transfer', 'Transfer'),
        )

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='transactions', on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    bank_name = LowerField(max_length=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

signals also works

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

@receiver(pre_save, sender=YourModel)
def to_lower(sender, instance=None, **kwargs):
    instance.text = instance.text.lower() if  \
        isinstance(instance.text, str) else ''
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
        self.YourFildName = self.YourFildName.upper()
        super(YourFomrName, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```