# I have over written the save() method but the new code is only being applied to new records

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I need titles to be in lowercase. I overwrite the `save()` method and included `self.title.lower()`, this works great for any new records I create. But when I modify existing records, the titles are not changed to lowercase? Does anyone know why? Or could someone point me in the direction of the relevant documentation?

I have a many to many field in the table, should I update my `m2m_changed` signal to include code that addresses the issue?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
if not self.slug:
    self.slug = unique_slug_generator(self)
    self.title = self.title.lower()
            
    super(CategoryTree, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  
else:
    super(CategoryTree, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: How are you changing the existing records?

Comment: It is all sorted. Arakkal Abu spotted the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code, the title is being lowered only if the instance doesn't have a `slug`, which is usually at the creation of an object. So, I would recommend using an update operation *across the table*

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

CategoryTree.objects.update(title=Lower('title'))
```

Please note that this is a one-time operation, which will update every `title` value to corresponding lower cased values.

Alternatively, you can modify the **`save(...)`** method as

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = unique_slug_generator(self)

    if not self.title.islower():
        self.title = self.title.lower()

    super(CategoryTree, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. I was over thinking the problem. All I had to do was move self.title = self.title.lower() above the  if not self.slug statement.