# django heroku postgres db does not detect current migration django.db.utils.DataError: value too long

Tags: django, database, python-3.x, postgresql, heroku

When I run my script to populate my Django postgres DB, I get django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(30). To overcome this error, I changed my code to take URL of max length of 200 characters length.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class ArticleScheme(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    newsoutlet = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    polarity = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    subjectivity = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    keywords = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=10), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ("title:{}\nnewsoutet:{}\nurl:{}\ndate_joined:{}"
        + "\ntext:{}\npolarity:{}\nsubjectivity:{}\nkeywords:{}").format(
          self.title, self.newsoutlet, self.url, self.date_joined, self.text,
          self.polarity, self.subjectivity, str(self.keywords)
        )
```

I saved the file used command python3 manage.py makemigrations appname. I then push that code to Heroku. Using Heroku run bash, the migrations is in the folder, but python3 manage.py migrate appname does not detect a migration to update.
I run my script to to populate the database on Heroku and I get the error below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.DataError: value too long for type character varying(30)


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/HerokuNewsApp/management/commands/NewsScraper.py", line 133, in handle
    self.FindAndWriteArticle(options['url'], options["news"])
  File "/app/HerokuNewsApp/management/commands/NewsScraper.py", line 120, in FindAndWriteArticle
    self.AddArticleToDB(article, blob.sentiment, newsoutlet)
  File "/app/HerokuNewsApp/management/commands/NewsScraper.py", line 46, in AddArticleToDB
    ArticlePost.save()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 729, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 759, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 842, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 880, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1125, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1280, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(30)
```

Obviously, Django is failing to detect the update to my database for migration. I have tried deleting the migration manually and using makemigration command again with no luck. I also tried python manage.py makemigration --fake appname zero. However, I believe this also cause an error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried using TruncatingCharField as describe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459843/auto-truncating-fields-at-max-length-in-django-charfields, but I got the same django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(30).

Answer (score 0):

I reset the database on Heroku, and the code works after that. If you look at the documentation on Postgres, it says adding columns requires a full rewrite. I believe the problem was adding new entries with a higher length requires a rewrite as well.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#postgresql

Luckily, I did not any important data, but if you need the data, make a JSON file of the database entries before resetting the database. Then, you will be able to reload the data.